# Where did the ExportFactory<T> from desktop MEF go?

Tags: mef

I can't find it!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ExportFactory<T>` is not part of MEF for the desktop (yet - as of now, it's only released for Silverlight).  It looks like it will be included in MEF 2.

In the meantime, Glenn Block posted a version of the [Composition.Initialization](http://cid-f8b2fd72406fb218.office.live.com/self.aspx/blog/Composition.Initialization.Desktop.zip) assembly ported to MEF for desktop development, and placed it on his SkyDrive.  Alternatively, you can use the [Preview 1 release of MEF2](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/48222), which includes this.